# Change time by clicking on . bat in windows

Tags: windows-7, cmd, batch-file, systemtime

I am developing a system where several i'm having to change date to Sunday February 06 3:30:50 AM.

Is there any way to create a .bat so that by clicking on it, the system automatically changes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the time and date commands:

```
time 03:30:50
date 06/02/2011
```

Comment: i'm using win 7, when i'm doing this , it is saying a required priviledge is not held by the client

Comment: @Noor: I have winXP, anyway, try this: http://aaronmargosis.members.winisp.net/MakeMeAdmin/MakeMeAdmin.zip, got from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/193721.aspx

Comment: @Noor: Just run the batch file with administrative privileges. I.e. right-click and »Run as administrator«.

Comment: THis is simple and nice.. Can it be converted to a batch script in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Answer obtained from BlackBear and  Joey:

Run cmd as Administrator 
Then type commands such as :

time 03:30:50
date 06/02/2011

Comment: Correct. You need to use your admin powers in order to change the system time.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: yeah, it might be dangerous ;)